# Performing a minor change in answer

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I wanted to add a simple change to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id/7303433#7303433) answer. The problem is that my change

```
http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html
to
http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html
```

does not meet the required amount of changed characters(6).
Also i sadly cannot leave a comment, because i do not have enough reputation.

My Question is now, what the intended way is to get this change done.

Comment: Leave a comment.

Comment: It states "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

Comment: Is there nothing else in that post to be improved? If not, just move on.

Comment: I made the change for now. Generally I would advise to look for other parts of the post that need changing as well (spelling/grammar/whatever), but in this case you would simply have no option than to leave it as is until you can leave a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way for you to make that change in this specific case.

Generally I would advise 2 things:

- Check if there are other changes that need to be made (spelling/grammar/formatting corrections), and see if that takes you over the minimum edit requirements
- Leave a comment suggesting the edit.

In this specific case, and given your current reputation, neither seem to be an option. In that case you have no other option than to just let it go. A last alternative would be to notify someone in a topic-related chat room, but only if you have enough reputation for that, and they welcome such requests in the room.

Unfortunately the downsides of reducing any requirements would would outweigh benefit.

But in this case I have made the edit for you.

Comment: Thanks for making the edit and reminding me of chat rooms I did not think of that.